# How can i get generic type from a Class object?

Tags: java, generics, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose the following class

```
public class Message {
    // some code
}
```

And a Spring Validator implementation (no Spring knowledge required)

```
public class MessageValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(Message.class))
            return true;
        else if(<ANSWER>)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void validate(Object command, Errors errorArray) {
        if(command instanceof List)
            for(Message message: (List) command)
                validateMessage(message);
        else
            validateMessage((Message) command);
    }

    public void validateMessage(Message message, Errors errorArray) {
        // do validation Message object
    }

}
```

Notice supports method. What to put in <ANSWER> in order to support a List of Message - List<Message> ?

regards,

Comment: There is generic information in class object so I do not think you can check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type argument information is (mostly) not retained at runtime so you don't have an easy way of accessing it. Basically, even though it says `List<Message>` it could still be a `List<String>`. There is no way of distinguishing the two without inspecting all the elements.

The best you can do is see if it implements `List`. Welcome to type erasure.

Comment: +1. However, it's not the end of the world in this particular case. You can always check the actual type of `List` element within `validate()` method and skip the validation if it's not `Message`.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth remembering the following distinction:

*Objects* don't have generic types.  An actual `List` instance is just a straight `ArrayList`, or `LinkedList`, or whatever.  The object itself does not have a generic type nor does it care about generics.

*Variables* on the other hand are declared generically.  So you'd reference the object as a `List<Foo>`.  This allows the compiler to enforce type-safety, but what you're really saying is that you want to *treat* the (untyped) `List` as a list of `Foo`, and you're asking the compiler to stop you from making calls that would insert `Bar`s (for example).

Generics is just a compile time 'trick' built on top of the existing objects, so it makes no sense to check at runtime whether an object is an instance of `List<Foo>` - it's just an instance of `List`.  In addition, runtime checking doesn't gain you anything since if it can't be checked at compile time, you get no benefit from the generics anyway.